# removing 'recent' files names from finder in MacOS

Tags: macos, finder

There are about 5000 recents in my recents on finder. Can these be deleted or does this also delete the files themselves

Comment: Can you add a screenshot so we know about which menu/window you are talking about here?

Comment: @nohillside, The max for  > Recent Items is 50, so if the OP says "There are about 5000 recents in my recents on finder" it has to be referring to Finder > Go > Recents, so a picture shouldn't really be necessary.

Comment: A screen shot would be good here - we don’t know if they have a saved spotlight search, the normal spotlight search (which matches up with 5000) items or their recent menu is somehow broken (which I have yet to see show more than 100 items - broken or healthy)

Answer (score 5):

I'm assuming you are talking about Finder > Go > Recents

Files there cannot be deleted without deleting the files themselves. It's just an alternate view of the files on your computer.

(If you are instead talking about the Apple Menu > Recent Items or Finder > Go > Recent Folders, those both have a "Clear Menu" option at the bottom of the menu)

see:
https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8137012

Comment: I thought so but am apple support person told my wife to delete them. Fortunately her multi-hour backups have everything! Thank you for your response

Comment: @Donald Platt, Just an FYI... A single file could have been selected and deleted to see what would happen and one would have easily found out that deleting a file in Recents does in fact move the file to the Trash, where it could have easily been put back. No need to call Apple or delete all the files to then have to restore them from backup!

Answer (score 1):

Just right click and remove from side bar and then you won’t see the recents folder, that what I’ve done :) To be clear this ONLY removes 'Recents' from the sidebar NOT finder/go dropdown